# OneDrive Business REST + Java uploading large files - Does "setChunkedStreamingMode" work?

Tags: java, onedrive

For large files uploaded to OneDrive Business, I need to be able to send the 'content' in chunks, otherwise I get an OutOfMemoryError.

Does the 'setChunkedStreamingMode' method work?
The server is returning status code 500.
I am not having any success sending batched content to the server.
Here is the Java code that I am using.

```
private static void testChunkUpload()
{        
    String accessToken = "eJO...";  // I'm using a valid token

    try {
        String parentId = "01TOQ6QQ6KQBXXTKT4ABE3S6LDF4HE5PT5";
        String filename = "XYZ.txt";

        String fileContentString = "contents of the file.";
        byte[] fileContents = fileContentString.getBytes();

        StringBuilder dlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        dlBuilder.append( "https://test-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me" ) // I'm using the correct URL
                .append("/files/")
                .append(parentId)
                .append("/children/")
                .append(filename)
                .append("/content");

        URL uploadURL = new URL( dlBuilder.toString() );

        HttpURLConnection uploadConn = (HttpURLConnection)uploadURL.openConnection();

        uploadConn.setRequestMethod( "PUT" );
        uploadConn.setUseCaches(false);
        uploadConn.setDoOutput( true );         

        uploadConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);  // this is right
        uploadConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html");

        uploadConn.setChunkedStreamingMode( 0 );
        try (OutputStream os = uploadConn.getOutputStream()) {
            os.write(fileContents);
            os.flush();
        }

        System.out.println(uploadConn.getResponseCode());

        uploadConn.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestOneDrive.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestOneDrive.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I have tried all manner of request property combinations.
If I don't write any content to the output stream, I create an empty file on the server, so part of this is working.

Has anyone had any success batching content to OneDrive for Business?
At this point, I'm not sure if the server supports it.

Answer (score 0):

The API supports batch requests but it doesn't look like it supports chunked.  You might want to look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn903506%28v=office.15%29.aspx for more information on making batch requests with the API.  I hope that helps.

Comment: That type of batching is sending more than one REST command at once. I need to send the contents of a large file to the server in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Move the line `setDoOutput(true)` before `setRequestMethod("PUT").`

Otherwise you will execute a POST, not a PUT.

And yes, chunked streaming mode works.

Comment: Moving the setDoOutput(true) did not make a difference.

Comment: I've seen the 'setChunkedStreamingMode' method work with 'OneDrive' but not 'OneDrive for Business'.